# Devise before_save filter not applying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Before my User's can register I need to authenticate them via api first to see if their information is valid. Anyhow I have my validate_api method working as it needs to be I have tested this however, I'm not sure as to why when i try to register with a faulty api it still saves the user.

I put my method in a controller and called it with a valid api and it returned true and then with faulty api and it returned false.

So if the method is working it's either being ignored or something overrides it.

My User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :login

    before_save :validate_api

    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
    # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:login]

    validates :username, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 6, :maximum => 255 }
    validates :apiid, :presence => true, :numericality => { :only_integer => true }
    validates :vcode, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 20, :maximum => 255 }

    # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
    attr_accessible :login, :username, :group, :apiid, :vcode, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

    # Check if user is banned before login
    def active_for_authentication?
      super && self.banned == 0
    end

    # Redefine authentication procedure to allow login with username or email
    def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login).downcase
        #where(conditions).where('$or' => [ {:username => /^#{Regexp.escape(login)}$/i}, {:email => /^#{Regexp.escape(login)}$/i} ]).first
        where(conditions).where("username = '#{login}' OR email = '#{login}'").first
      else
        where(conditions).first
      end
    end

    # Validate API information
    private
    def validate_api

        require 'nokogiri'
        require 'open-uri'

        uri = "https://*******?keyID=#{self.apiid}&vCode=#{self.vcode}"
        xml = Nokogiri::XML(open(uri))

        xml.xpath("//row").each do |row|
            if row['****'].downcase == '****'
                return true
            else
                return false                
            end
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Why don't you debug? You will see what is called and whether it runs before filter

Comment: Try making ```validate_api``` ```protected``` method not   ```private``` and as Aleks suggested add a debug message inside to see if it's being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `before_save :validate_api` you should be using `validate :check_api`, and then adding an error message (eg: `errors[:apiid] << "must be a valid API id."`) if the api check fails.